# How can i move this Select Statement with Top

Tags: sql, join, subquery, row-number

I'm trying to optimize this query to use a join instead of this sub query, but with the `Top 1`, I'm a little confused.

```
SELECT
    s.ItemNumber
    s.ImportKey
    ,(
        SELECT top 1 MerchandiseGroupID 
        FROM MerchandiseGroup mg 
        WHERE s.StoreDepartment = mg.Name AND c.ClientNumber = s.ClientNumber
    ) as MerchandiseGroupID
FROM dbo.Source s 
INNER JOIN dbo.Client c on s.ClientNumber = c.ClientNumber
INNER JOIN dbo.ClientVendor cv on s.Vendor = cv.ClientVendorName
INNER JOIN dbo.TypeClientWarehouse tw on c.WarehouseCode = tw.WarehouseCode
WHERE s.ImportDate > '2014-05-15 01:00:00.000'
```

What I have so far:

```
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY MerchandiseGroupID asc) rnum,
        MerchandiseGroupID,
        Name 
    FROM MerchandiseGroup mg
) mhg
    ON s.StoreDepartment = mg.Name AND c.ClientNumber = s.ClientNumber
WHERE s.ImportDate > '2014-05-15 01:00:00.000' AND mg.rnum = 1
```

Comment: No matter what approach you take, a where clause in the subquery will make it run faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using TOP 1 is no less optimal that turning it into a join and using ROW_NUMBER(), however if the reason you want a join is so you can get other fields from the tables then use an [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (Your first query has no order by with the top so I have assumed it to be the same as in your ROW_NUMBER function in the JOIN attempt):

```
SELECT
    s.ItemNumber,
    s.ImportKey,
    mg.MerchandiseGroupID,
    mg.Name
FROM dbo.Source s 
INNER JOIN dbo.Client c on s.ClientNumber = c.ClientNumber
INNER JOIN dbo.ClientVendor cv on s.Vendor = cv.ClientVendorName
INNER JOIN dbo.TypeClientWarehouse tw on c.WarehouseCode = tw.WarehouseCode
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT top 1 MerchandiseGroupID, Name
    FROM MerchandiseGroup mg 
    WHERE s.StoreDepartment = mg.Name 
    AND c.ClientNumber = s.ClientNumber
    ORDER BY MerchandiseGroupID
) mg
WHERE s.ImportDate > '2014-05-15 01:00:00.000'
```

This approach tends to be faster than ROW_NUMBER if you only want the top 1, it is less flexible if you want specific records though, such as the 3rd record.

Not related, but becareful when using the date format you have, even though this is the ISO standard it can still throw an error:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT  CAST('2014-05-15 01:00:00.000' AS DATETIME);
```

Will give you:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>
> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.